# How to set the value of an entity reference field with the value of another entity reference field in a hook function - D9

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-9

I am using a hook function to create a commerce product when a node type of PL is created.

I have 2 Entity Reference fields:

1. Name of Project - Which references content
2. Type of Use - Which references a taxonomy term

Everything works and the title field is set correctly except for the 2 field values, **field_name_of_project** and **field_type_of_use**.

What could I be doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
    <?php

/**
 * @file
 * file for the PL Product Creation module, which creates a product and product variations when a Pl node is created.
 *
 */ 

use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;
use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductVariation;
use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait;

/**
 * Implementation of hook_entity_insert().
 */
function pl_product_creation_entity_insert(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
    if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'node' && $entity->bundle() == 'pl_node') {
        // Get the pl node properties
        $name_of_project = $entity->field_name_of_project->entity->getTitle();
        $type_of_use = $entity->field_type_of_use->entity->getName();
  
  
        // Load the product
        $pl_product_title = 'Products at ' . $name_of_project;

        // Load the product storage.
        $entity_type_manager = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager');
        $product_storage = $entity_type_manager->getStorage('commerce_product');

        // Load the product by title.
        $pl_product = $product_storage->loadByProperties(['title' => $pl_product_title]);
  
        // Check if the Pl product exists
        if (!empty($pl_product)) {
            // Load the Pl product
            $pl_product = reset($pl_product);
        }
        else {
            // Create a new Pl product
            $pl_product = Product::create([
                'type' => 'pl',
            ]);

            // Set the title field.
            $pl_product->setTitle($pl_product_title);

            // Set the values of the custom fields.
            $pl_product->set('field_name_of_project', $name_of_project);
            $pl_product->set('field_type_of_use', $type_of_use);

            // Save the product entity.
            $pl_product->save();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to figure it out. Posting here in case someone needs this in the future.

```
// Set the values of the custom fields.
  $pl_product->set('field_name_of_project', $entity->field_name_of_project->entity);
  $pl_product->set('field_type_of_use', $entity->field_type_of_use->entity);
```